# Semantic-ui tabs when loading url scripts are not working in the tab

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, tabs, semantic-ui

I am facing a problem where when i load a url into a tab the scripts on the parent page such as dropdown etc. doesn't work inside that tab so in order to make the new tab content work i have to add all scripts to the page i call in something i don't want to do. If i add the content in the parent page manually without loading through a url then all works but i prefer to load pages. So if i want to dynamically load html of another page is another way to make it work through semantic-ui or should i use pjax for that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For those who may have the same problem/question with me...
After hours of searching i found out and realized that in order to get the scripts working i have to include them on a .js file instead of using  in the parent page because after a new page load, scripts where already executed. So either include your inline scripts in a .js file or in the page you are loading but not in your master page unless you include them on a .js file.
This is also the same for pjax.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the Semantic UI "[api settings](http://semantic-ui.com/behaviors/api.html)" in your js.

API settings for tabs;

```
$.fn.api.settings.api = {
    'get gallery'       : '/gallery.html',
    'get youtube'       : '/youtube.html'
};
```

Please take a look at working sample : [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/UnderlineWords/y62aeqL7/1/).
I hope this would help you!

Comment: Thank you but it's not the solution i am looking for. The problem was that after loading a tab dropdown and other js didn't work as expected. I found a solution after hours of searching though.